# jquery backgroundpositionY animation not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So I have a background I want to animate on a scroll event, works fine in chrome and safari.

Apparently though, firefox doesn't support this properly (and neither does opera).

Is there some other property I can use to animate the background that'll work cross browser?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 200) {
        $(".col-3-iphoneback").animate( { backgroundPositionY:"-223px"}, { queue:false, duration:1000 });
    } 


     if (scroll <= 200) {
        $(".col-3-iphoneback").animate( { backgroundPositionY:"0px" }, { queue:false, duration:1000 } );
    } 


});
```

Comment: Does no one have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

`backgroundPositionY` is not a standard CSS property, so it doesn't supported by Firefox and Opera. You would need to use one of these cssHooks for jQuery:

https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundXY.js/blob/master/jquery.backgroundXY.js  https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-cssHooks/blob/master/bgpos.js